# Can we use a GIF in an WKImageView?

Tags: ios, gif, watchkit

I want to use a **GIF** in an **Image** on *WatchKit*, it is possible ?

I think is not possible but maybe you know

Thank you in advance

P.S : I'm french so if you speak french it suits me.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the `WKInterfaceImage` [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceImage_class/), under "Animating a Series of Images", you'll see the following:

> You create animated images from a set of local image file resources or from existing UIImage objects. You use them to construct a new UIImage object, which you then assign to your WKInterfaceImage object.

So, yes, you can do it. But you need to provide a series of static images rather than a finished GIF.